# add dictionaries to empty list dict.value()

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have four dictionaries I would like to add as items in empty list that is a dictionary value. and I have no idea how to do this. Could someone please help me figure out how to turn this:

```
data = {'Cars': []}

dict1 = {'subaru': 1, 'honda': 5, 'volkswagen': 8}
dict2 = {'subaru': 7, 'honda': 3, 'volkswagen': 9}
dict3 = {'subaru': 9, 'honda': 2, 'volkswagen': 1}
dict4 = {'subaru': 2, 'honda': 8, 'volkswagen': 2}

print (data)
```

into this:

```
{'Cars': [{'subaru': 1, 'honda': 5, 'volkswagen': 8},
          {'subaru': 7, 'honda': 3, 'volkswagen': 9},
          {'subaru': 9, 'honda': 2, 'volkswagen': 1},
          {'subaru': 2, 'honda': 8, 'volkswagen': 2}]}
```

Comment: `data['Cars']` is your initially-empty list.  You add elements to a list by calling `.append()` on it.  Thus, `data['Cars'].append(dict1)`, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {'Cars': []}
dict1 = {'subaru': 1, 'honda': 5, 'volkswagen': 8}
dict2 = {'subaru': 7, 'honda': 3, 'volkswagen': 9}
dict3 = {'subaru': 9, 'honda': 2, 'volkswagen': 1}
dict4 = {'subaru': 2, 'honda': 8, 'volkswagen': 2}
```

> ```
> for item in [dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4]: 
>     data['Cars'].append(item)
> ```

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
pp.pprint(data)
```

gives:

```
{'Cars': [{'subaru': 1, 'honda': 5, 'volkswagen': 8}, 
          {'subaru': 7, 'honda': 3, 'volkswagen': 9}, 
          {'subaru': 9, 'honda': 2, 'volkswagen': 1}, 
          {'subaru': 2, 'honda': 8, 'volkswagen': 2}]}
```

Citation: """`data['Cars']` is your initially-empty list. You add elements to a list by calling `.append()` on it. Thus, `data['Cars'].append(dict1)`, and so on.""" – jasonharper

and this can be done in one step in a loop constructed as above.

To get the *pretty print* you `import` the [**`pprint`** module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html), create a `pp` object using `pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()` and use it's `pp.pprint()` function to print the list nested in the dictionary in a *pretty* way :) .

By the way: you can create the `data` dictionary with a list already containing the elements in one step using:

```
data = {'Cars': [
    {'subaru': 1, 'honda': 5, 'volkswagen': 8}, 
    {'subaru': 7, 'honda': 3, 'volkswagen': 9},
    {'subaru': 9, 'honda': 2, 'volkswagen': 1},
    {'subaru': 2, 'honda': 8, 'volkswagen': 2}]}
```

Comment: Please do not use list comprehensions as a loop statement replacement. That is bad style and creates an unnecessary list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `Cars` key in the `data` dictionary, then append to that.

```
data = {'Cars': []}

dict1 = {'subaru': 1, 'honda': 5, 'volkswagen': 8}
dict2 = {'subaru': 7, 'honda': 3, 'volkswagen': 9}
dict3 = {'subaru': 9, 'honda': 2, 'volkswagen': 1}
dict4 = {'subaru': 2, 'honda': 8, 'volkswagen': 2}

data['Cars'].append(dict1)
data['Cars'].append(dict2)
data['Cars'].append(dict3)
data['Cars'].append(dict4)
```

You could simplify this to just

```
data['Cars'].append({'subaru': 1, 'honda': 5, 'volkswagen': 8})
data['Cars'].append({'subaru': 7, 'honda': 3, 'volkswagen': 9})
data['Cars'].append({'subaru': 9, 'honda': 2, 'volkswagen': 1})
data['Cars'].append({'subaru': 2, 'honda': 8, 'volkswagen': 2})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append all the dicts to your `data["Cars"]` which is a list.

```
for i in [dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4]:
    data["Cars"].append(i)

print data
```